# Change the color of overflow menu icons in a material toolbar

Tags: android, android-toolbar, material-components-android, material-components

I want to change the overflow menu icons color in my material toolbar depending on the `android:theme` value.

In this example my search icon is affected by the toolbar's theme via some magic related to the `app:actionViewClass` attribute implementation, but my info icon is not.

My toolbar:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    app:liftOnScroll="true">

    <com.google.android.material.appbar.MaterialToolbar
        android:id="@+id/toolbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
        android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.MaterialComponents.Dark.ActionBar"
        style="@style/Widget.MaterialComponents.Toolbar.Primary"
        app:title="@string/app_name"
        app:menu="@menu/menu_main"
        app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|enterAlways|snap"/>

</com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout>
```

My menu:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<menu
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">

    <item
        android:id="@+id/action_search"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_search_24dp"
        app:showAsAction="always"
        app:actionViewClass="androidx.appcompat.widget.SearchView"
        android:title="TODO" />

    <item android:id="@+id/action_info"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_info_24dp"
        app:showAsAction="always"
        android:title="TODO" />

</menu>
```

Does a simple solution exists?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can head over to the Material Components documentation which has a lot of information about styling each part of views from the library.

In this case it seems like the action icon tint is set by the `colorControlNormal` attribute.

Documentation - [Top app bars](https://material.io/develop/android/components/top-app-bars/)

Answer (score 5):

You can use:

```
<com.google.android.material.appbar.MaterialToolbar
    style="@style/Widget.MaterialComponents.Toolbar.Primary"
    android:theme="@style/MyThemeOverlay_Toolbar"
    ...>

  <style name="MyThemeOverlay_Toolbar" parent="ThemeOverlay.MaterialComponents.Toolbar.Primary">
    <!-- color used by navigation icon and overflow icon -->
    <item name="colorOnPrimary">@color/myColor</item>
  </style>
```

Comment: I've seen this answer in many similar question but it doesn't actually work for me, does this behave as we expect on your machine?

Comment: @Fabio which version of Material Components are you using?

Comment: The stable version 1.1.0 - Edit: just tried with the 1.3.0-alpha01, same behaviour

Comment: @Fabio Just tried in a clean project with `1.1.0`, `1.2.0-beta01`, `1.3.0-alpha01`. it works. Pay attention to the `parent="ThemeOverlay.MaterialComponents.Toolbar.Primary"` in your theme overlay.

Comment: that's peculiar, are you using android studio 4.0 version too?

Comment: @GabrieleMariotti How can I change color for menu items which are not overflowed?

Comment: @GabrieleMariotti I noticed that with this approach, the menu item that changes color is the one with app:showAsAction="never". The others keep the color of the drawable. Any idea? Using material:1.9.0. with 1.3.0-alpha01 your solutions works

Comment: Actually I noticed that up to 1.4.0, it works if in the toolbar style (Widget.MaterialComponents.Toolbar.Primary) I set     <item name="navigationIconTint">@color/white</item>. The solution you suggest it is only applied to the item app:showAsAction="never".

Answer (score 5):

Maybe this answer comes too late, but just in case other people need it, I will post my answer here.

The problem you are facing will be solved if you set the attribute **theme** to the **AppBarLayout** instead of the **MaterialToolbar**.

So, in your code, your toolbar should look like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.MaterialComponents.Dark.ActionBar"
    app:liftOnScroll="true">

    <com.google.android.material.appbar.MaterialToolbar
        android:id="@+id/toolbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
        style="@style/Widget.MaterialComponents.Toolbar.Primary"
        app:title="@string/app_name"
        app:menu="@menu/menu_main"
        app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|enterAlways|snap"/>

</com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout>
```

Hope this helps to anyone!

Answer (score 0):

There are many answers about `Actionbar Toolbar MaterialToolbar`, But the sample way is set icon color in code. Here are some code below to show you how to set icon color in activity:

```
    override fun onCreateOptionsMenu(menu: Menu): Boolean {
    menuInflater.inflate(R.menu.menu_activity_main, menu)

    val iconColor = ContextCompat.getColor(this, R.color.toolbar_action_menu_icon)
    for (index in 0 until menu.size) {
        val menuItem = menu.getItem(index)
        DrawableCompat.setTint(
            menuItem.icon,
            iconColor
        )
    }
    return true
}
```

`menu_activity_main` is your menu file, and `toolbar_action_menu_icon` is your menu icon color defined in color.xml file.